# Picard group and the blow up - projectivization isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry

It is well known that $Y$, the blow up of $\mathbb{P}^2$ at a point is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(\mathcal{O}\oplus \mathcal{O}(1)$). Then Picard group  of $Y$ can be written in two manners. From the blow up point of view:

$$Pic(Y)=\mathbb{Z}H\oplus \mathbb{Z}E$$
where $H$ is the pull back of a hyperplane section  in $\mathbb{P}^2$ and $E$ is the exceptional divisor.

From the projectivization point of view,

$$Pic(Y)=Pic(\mathbb{P}^1)\oplus \mathbb{Z} \mathcal{O}(1)$$

where $\mathcal{O}(1)$ is the tautological line bundle for the Proj construction. We  will denoted the elements in this splitting by $\mathcal{O}(a,b)$.

My questions is: what does $\mathcal{O}(1,0)$, $\mathcal{O}(0,1)$ corresponds to in the base of $H$ and $E$?

I suppose the answer should also extend to higher dimension when you have a blow up of $\mathbb{P}^n$ at linear subvaireties?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Specified the second splitting

Comment: The splitting $Pic(Y) = Pic(\mathbb{P}^1) \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ is not canonical, and the answer (of course) depends on the choice of the splitting.

Comment: @Sasha That's a great point, I will edit my question. Thanks!

Comment: There is still some ambiguity about what you call the projectivization --- there are two compteteng conventions: the Grothendick's convention is $\mathbb{P}(F) := \mathrm{Proj}\left(\bigoplus_{i=0}^\infty S^iF \right)$ and the alternative convention $\mathbb{P}(F) := \mathrm{Proj}\left(\bigoplus_{i=0}^\infty S^iF^\vee \right)$. Whi do you use?

Comment: @Sasha I am using the first one. Thanks!

Comment: Then $\mathcal{O}(1)$ corresponds to $H$ and the (ample) generator of $\mathbb{P}^1$ is $H-E$.